# Guardar imagenes en sqlite android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, blob

Hola estoy probando un ejemplo para guardar fotos en sqlite, he conseguido mostrar una imagen de la galeria, pero nose como guardarla.Gracias.

```
//cargar foto en imagenView
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE){
        imageUri = data.getData();
        IMGView.setImageURI(imageUri);

        //pasar a mapa de bits
        Bitmap bitmap = IMGView.getDrawingCache();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Si es mejor de guardar el imagen en un [*Datatype*](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) Blob, o en un archivo con la ruta como referencia en la tabla depende del tamaño de tus imagenes.

Tu puedes encontrar una tabla que indica hasta que tamaño es factible de guardar un Blob directamente en la tabla en [esta pagina](https://sqlite.org/intern-v-extern-blob.html). Como se ve, hasta un tamaño de 20k siempre es factible de guardar el Blob directo, con tamaños más grande eso depende del tamaño de pagina en el acceso a SQLite.

Las [versiones de SQLite usado en Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html) actualmente son todos anteriores a 3.12, significando que el tamaño de pagina por defecto es 1024 bytes.

Para cambiar el tamaño de pagina se puede usar [`PRAGMA`](https://sqlite.org/pragma.html), **antes** de crear la tabla:

```
PRAGMA page_size = 4096;
```

(El `Pragma` puedes por ejemplo agregar en `onCreate` de tu `SQLiteOpenHelper`)

**El procedimiento para guardar los imagenes desde un `Bitmap` seria:**

- comprimir el bitmap en un `ByteArrayOutputStream`
- escribir el `byte[]` del stream como blob en tu tabla:
- se asume una tabla `CREATE TABLE imagenes (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, img BLOB);` con un [SQLiteOpenHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) helper

En código:

```
public void guardarImagen(long id, Bitmap bitmap){
    // tamaño del baos depende del tamaño de tus imagenes en promedio
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(20480);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0 , baos);
    byte[] blob = baos.toByteArray();
    // aqui tenemos el byte[] con el imagen comprimido, ahora lo guardemos en SQLite
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

    String sql = "INSERT INTO imagenes (id, img) VALUES(?,?)";
    SQLiteStatement insert = db.compileStatement(sql);
    insert.clearBindings();
    insert.bindLong(1, id));
    insert.bindBlob(2, blob);
    insert.executeInsert();
    db.close();
}
```

Para recuperar un imagen según `id` se puede usar:

```
public Bitmap buscarImagen(long id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();

    String sql = String.format("SELECT * FROM imagenes WHERE id = %d", id);
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[] {});
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        byte[] blob = cursor.getBlob(1);
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(blob);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bais);
    }
    if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }
    db.close();
    return bitmap; 
}
```

Comment: cual es la ruta de la imagen? o donde la encuentro

Answer (score 1):

Para guardar una imagen en una base de datos debes guardar la ruta del archivo. Es decir que cuando hagas un `insert` de la imagen a la BD debes de hacer el `insert` de la ruta. Tambien deberás de tener en cuenta que el archivo se copie al fichero de tu app.